# Newbie Database Design - "Stack Overflow style voting system"

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

This is a simplified version of the database design I have so far, for a 'Stack Overflow' style voting system.

The question is: if the user has a score for the total number of votes they got for a response, should that score be worked out 'on the fly' or should there be a field in the users table referring to their score. Also if the case is the the later, what would the recommended method be for keeping it up to date?

```
Users Table
-id
-name
-email

Question Table
-id
-text
-poster (user id)

Responses Table
-id
-text
-question (question id)
-poster (user id)

Votes Table
-id
-response (response id)
-voter (user id)
```

Comment: You also should add votes and bookmark/favorite tables for the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De-normalizing the database model so a few critical scenarios can have better performance is justified, as long as you do it in a careful and deliberate fashion.

So **after** you have benchmarked the realistic amount of data and determined that counting votes on the fly causes performance problems, go right ahead and cache the vote count.

Probably the most robust way to keep the cached value up-to-date is to implement a database trigger that increments the cached value whenever a row is inserted into `Votes` and decrements it when a row is deleted.

(*NOTE: Having a `SELECT COUNT(*)...` trigger can introduce subtle concurrency issues.*)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest working out the vote total on demand, in the beginning at least.  Demand will probably be low as it begins use, and it can be changed later to being stored as a field in the Responses table.  When/if that happens, update it with a trigger.  Also, set up a view to report the responses and totals off of, so when/if the change is made, you have a central place to make an interface update instead of hunting down queries in your code.

This has the added benefit of being more flexible if the requirements change during the development or after the initial release.  Watch for feature creep.

You can also remove the id field in the Votes table.  If each vote is unique to response and voter, it's sufficient to make those fields keys to the table.

Comment: I'll remove that id on the Votes table, thanks and replace it with a combined key using those two foreign keys

Answer (score 2):

You would probably want let the schema allow for votes on questions as well (meaning that would need another vote table). I think it would be a good idea to have a vote sum (reputation) in the `Users` table, since it would be more effective to query a single row in a table than to query a sum over two tables each time you wanted to display a user's reputation. You could either update this from triggers or from your business logic. You also need to think about how you would represent up/down-votes. You could do this with either a bit value (representing up or down) or an absolute number (1/-1) in both the vote tables. You would have to adjust the total in the `Users` table every time an entry is inserted, deleted or updated in both the voting tables. It would probably be a bit more "fool proof" to update the total through triggers, but you could also argue that it should live in your business logic layer, and that people should not be playing around in the tables directly anyways. But as long as you take an informed decision I personally don't think that it matters much.